# error in a constructor in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

does someone know what is the problem with my box renderer constructor ?
sometimes this error occurs:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> 04-04 12:39:20.507 D/Mono    ( 5408): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
>   04-04 12:39:20.507 D/Mono    ( 5408): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
>   04-04 12:39:20.507 D/Mono    ( 5408): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
>   04-04 12:39:20.507 D/Mono    ( 5408): Searching for '__android_log_print'.
>   04-04 12:39:20.507 D/Mono    ( 5408): Probing '__android_log_print'.
>   04-04 12:39:20.507 D/Mono    ( 5408): Found as '__android_log_print'.
>   04-04 12:39:20.517 I/MonoDroid( 5408): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   04-04 12:39:20.537 I/MonoDroid( 5408): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   04-04 12:39:20.537 I/MonoDroid( 5408):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.MotionEventHelper.HandleMotionEvent (Android.Views.IViewParent parent, Android.Views.MotionEvent motionEvent) [0x00000] in D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\MotionEventHelper.cs:12 
>   04-04 12:39:20.547 I/MonoDroid( 5408):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.BoxRenderer.OnTouchEvent (Android.Views.MotionEvent e) [0x0000b] in D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\BoxRenderer.cs:29 
>   04-04 12:39:20.547 I/MonoDroid( 5408):   at Android.Views.View.n_OnTouchEvent_Landroid_view_MotionEvent_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_e) [0x0000f] in :0 
>   04-04 12:39:20.547 I/MonoDroid( 5408):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:eb4269e7-cbad-45d7-bb9d-dbefa879d3e2 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
>   04-04 12:39:20.577 W/art     ( 5408): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable
>   04-04 12:39:20.577 D/Mono    ( 5408): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
>   04-04 12:39:20.577 D/Mono    ( 5408): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
>   04-04 12:39:20.577 D/Mono    ( 5408): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
>   04-04 12:39:20.577 D/Mono    ( 5408): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
>   Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> 04-04 12:39:22.407 I/MonoDroid( 5408): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   04-04 12:39:22.447 I/MonoDroid( 5408): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   04-04 12:39:22.447 I/MonoDroid( 5408):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:eb4269e7-cbad-45d7-bb9d-dbefa879d3e2 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
>   04-04 12:39:22.447 I/MonoDroid( 5408):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Java.Interop.NativeMethods:java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_boolean_method_a (intptr,intptr&,intptr,intptr,intptr,Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue*)
>   04-04 12:39:22.447 I/MonoDroid( 5408):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualBooleanMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00073] in :0 
>   04-04 12:39:22.447 I/MonoDroid( 5408):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualBooleanMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0005d] in :0 
>   04-04 12:39:22.447 I/MonoDroid( 5408):   at Android.Views.View.DispatchTouchEvent (Android.Views.MotionEvent e) [0x00031] in :0 
>   04-04 12:39:22.447 I/MonoDroid( 5408):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].DispatchTouchEvent (Android.Views.MotionEvent e) [0x0000a] in D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:63 
>   04-04 12:39:22.447 I/MonoDroid( 5408):   at Android.Views.View.n_DispatchTouchEvent_Landroid_view_MotionEvent_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_e) [0x0000f] in :0 
>   04-04 12:39:22.447 I/MonoDroid( 5408):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:186516ab-cbd3-43fb-877a-82dbb704b877 (intptr,intptr,intptr)

This is my code in android project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Android.Runtime;
using neoFly_Montana.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.BoxView), typeof(BoxRenderer))]
 namespace neoFly_Montana.Droid
{
public class BoxRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.BoxRenderer
{
    public BoxRenderer()
    { }

    protected BoxRenderer(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base()
    {
        if (javaReference == null || transfer == null)
        {
            var sx = 5;
        }
    }
}
}
```

--------------------update-----------------------

I tried

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Label), 
typeof(NeoFly_MontanaLabelRenderer))]
namespace neoFly_Montana.Droid
{
public class NeoFly_MontanaLabelRenderer : 
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.LabelRenderer
{
    public NeoFly_MontanaLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        if(context == null)
        {
            var sx = 5;
        }
    }      
}
}
```

but using this I back to see this error that I had solved with the first code that I posted here:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type neoFly_Montana.Droid.BoxRenderer from native handle 0xbe99e3ac

(sometime like that)

Then, now I am using this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using neoFly_Montana.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.BoxView), typeof(BoxRenderer))]
namespace neoFly_Montana.Droid
{
public class BoxRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.BoxRenderer
{
    public BoxRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        if(context == null)
        {
            var sx = 5;
        }
    }

    protected BoxRenderer(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base()
    {
        if (javaReference == null || transfer == null)
        {
            var sx = 5;
        }
    }
}
}
```

with this second constructor the *Unable to activate...* error stops but the *null reference* still here.

Comment: You should create a class called CustomBoxView that exted from BoxView and then you put `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomBoxView), typeof(BoxRenderer))]`

Comment: What version of Xamarin.Forms are you using?  If it's 2.5+, you shouldn't use the BoxRenderer constructor with zero parameters.

Comment: To extend what @DavidS just said, you should be using constructors with `Context` parameter. You can see how it's done in [this blog post](https://www.davidbritch.com/2017/11/xamarinforms-25-and-local-context-in.html) - that is, if you're using Xamarin.Forms 2.5+

Comment: I am using xamarin.forms 2.5+. A question: if I follow your example I need to create a class, "MyBoxView" for example in my PCL project, right?...then use this component in my xaml...

Comment: Can't I use "(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.BoxView)" directly instead create a class ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just bare in mind, that this will affect all of the `BoxView` elements used in your app.

Comment: if I use only this contstructor I see "System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type neoFly_Montana.Droid.BoxRenderer from native handle 0xbe99e3ac " I will update my question..